# Do consecutive window functions with the same partitioning cause additional shuffles?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have two different windows with the same partitioning:

```
window1 = Window.partitionBy("id")
window2 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
```

And then I call several consecutive window functions using them:

```
df.withColumn("col1", F.sum("x").over(window1))
  .withColumn("col2", F.first("x").over(window2))
```

And suppose `df` is not partitioned by `id`.

Will the computation of `col2` cause another shuffle or will it reuse the same partitioning?

Does adding

```
df.repartition("id")
```

before the computation cause any performance improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: only one shuffle occurs, `repartition` is useless here.

That's actually quite easy to verify.

```py
// sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 2, "2022-10-22"),
    (1, 3, "2022-11-22"),
    (2, 4, "2023-12-12"),
    (2, 5, "2021-01-01")], ['id', 'x', 'date'])

# let us now introduce 3 windows and see what happens:
window1 = Window.partitionBy("id")
window2 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
window3 = Window.partitionBy("x").orderBy("date")
```

Now, let us use `explain` on your code:

```py
df.withColumn("col1", f.sum("x").over(window1))\
  .withColumn("col2", f.first("x").over(window2))\
  .explain()
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Window [first(x#169L, false) windowspecdefinition(id#168L, date#170 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS col2#233L], [id#168L], [date#170 ASC NULLS FIRST]
   +- Sort [id#168L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#170 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Window [sum(x#169L) windowspecdefinition(id#168L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS col1#227L], [id#168L]
         +- Sort [id#168L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#168L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#164]
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#168L,x#169L,date#170
```

As you can see, only one Exchange (=shuffle). Adding `repartition` yields the exact same execution plan. No change at all:

```py
df.repartition("id")\
  .withColumn("col1", f.sum("x").over(window1))\
  .withColumn("col2", f.first("x").over(window2))\
  .explain()
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Window [first(x#169L, false) windowspecdefinition(id#168L, date#170 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS col2#246L], [id#168L], [date#170 ASC NULLS FIRST]
   +- Sort [id#168L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#170 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Window [sum(x#169L) windowspecdefinition(id#168L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS col1#240L], [id#168L]
         +- Sort [id#168L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#168L, 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, [id=#182]
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#168L,x#169L,date#170]
```

The takeaway here is that regardless of the way it does it, spark remembers that it has partitioned the data and how it did it to avoid having to do it again.

Finally, notice that with `window3`, that needs a different partitioning, we have two shuffles:

```py
df.withColumn("col1", f.sum("x").over(window1))\
  .withColumn("col2", f.first("id").over(window3))\
  .explain()
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Window [first(id#168L, false) windowspecdefinition(x#169L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS col2#259L], [x#169L]
   +- Sort [x#169L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(x#169L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#207]
         +- Window [sum(x#169L) windowspecdefinition(id#168L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS col1#253L], [id#168L]
            +- Sort [id#168L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#168L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#203]
                  +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#168L,x#169L,date#170
```